# How to Build a Data Driven Selenium WebDriver + Java + TestNG Framework

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, testng

I'm planning to automate some website using Selenium WebDriver + Java + POM(Page Object Model) + TestNG.

I've all other WebPages common for the given website but for each transaction one WebPage which is almost like a form would be different.

So, I've following choices.

1. Have a Page Object Model (POM) Created for all static common pages and Start creating POMs for the pages which differs in each transaction.
2. Have a Page Object Model (POM) Created for all static common pages and using some external data source (XML, Excel etc) I can generate the tests for that perticular page.

I'm in favour of second approach here as I don't need to write code again for each new transaction just because there is one page is different?

Any thoughts? or anybody implemented something like this already?

Answer (score 1):

Yes 2nd approach- 'Page Obj model' based is best to keep your code isolated and easily maintainable.

For your test data maintenance I'd suggest you using Cucumber based (BDD driven) framework.

It goes very well with automation FW (POM, Selenium, Java, TestNG/Junit and Maven based) projects.

By using cucumber you need not depend on any other source of test data, i.e. excel or xml, this can easily be maintaned with feature files of cucumber.

Also BDD gives you the main advantage of keeping 'BA-QA-DEV and Management' on same page.
If you dont want to use Cucumber/BDD, then you can use Test NG data provider feature with Excel to achieve better test data management.

If you want to learn Cucumber/BDD-> there are lots of very good video tutorials available online. One of my Fav is here-
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6tu16kXT9PpteusHGISu_lHcV6MbBtA6

for web reading:
https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/automation-testing-with-selenium-cucumber-testng/

Happy Testing!

Comment: Yeah! Cucumber is the best in this cases 

Answer (score 0):

I have worked in similar kind of project. I would suggest to with #1. The reason is that might be possible in future you find difference in web pages, So common function will not be always applicable to each page.

So if you go with #2 as of now then its fine but you gonna end up by following #1 in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are mixing the Page object model with a data-driven framework.
Basically in data-driven framework, the data is read from an external file

Well if you want to build a simple pure data-driven framework then it should have

1. Independent tests
2. All tests should read data from JSON/XML/YAML/XLS... any source
3. Properties file having your locators and other settings
4. You should also create a base class which will have the common reusable functions which can be used in tests
5. You should make it in such a way that running on grid is easy and by just chaning external flag.. tests should run in GRID
6. Proper HTML reporting with screenshots, errors, failures should be done

Also watch this video
https://youtu.be/s-W8pw9GnWc